# Maya/Python Assistance! Anyone familiar with Maya API?

Tags: python, maya

So..what I'm trying to do is change the reference (i.e. to a file C:/User/Desktop/file01/Cindi.ma)..how would I use the Python code to change that reference to C:/User/Desktop/file02/Cindi.ma? Any help appreciated

Comment: Show your code. Look at this: http://sscce.org/ . You'll want to change to a more descriptive title as well, to get more responses.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import maya.cmds as mc

#First query the reference node name to replace reference. 
rfn = mc.file( "C:/User/Desktop/file01/Cindi.ma", q=1, rfn=1 )

#then use reference node name(rfn) to replace the path.
mc.file ( "C:/User/Desktop/file02/Cindi.ma", loadReference=rfn, type="mayaAscii", options="v=0")
```